# Bash script problems

Tags: bash

This is my bash file script using Nexus Repository Manager API:

```
# Send Setup script
curl -u admin:admin123 -X POST --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
http://localhost:8081/service/rest/v1/script \
-d @setup.json

# Test scripts
printf "---------------------- SCRIPTS ----------------------"
curl -u admin:admin123 -X GET http://localhost:8081/service/rest/v1/script

# Run script
curl -u admin:admin123 -X POST --header 'Content-Type: text/plain' \
 http://localhost:8081/service/rest/v1/script/setup/run
```

When I run it the input is:

```
curl: (3) Illegal characters found in URL
./setup.sh: line 3: http://localhost:8081/service/rest/v1/script: No such file or directory
./setup.sh: line 4: -d: command not found
./setup.sh: line 5: $'\r': command not found
./setup.sh: line 7: printf: --: invalid option
printf: usage: printf [-v var] format [arguments]
curl: (3) Illegal characters found in URL
./setup.sh: line 9: $'\r': command not found
curl: (3) Illegal characters found in URL
: No such file or directory/localhost:8081/service/rest/v1/script/setup/run
./setup.sh: line 13: $'\r': command not found
```

Where is the problem? Is it problem with backslashes?

Comment: What kind of line endings does the (script) file have?

Comment: It is CR LF ...

Comment: Then that’s the problem (except, perhaps, for the `printf` error).

Comment: POSIX-based systems use `\n` as a line ending. the `\r` characters are confusing matters. That is, you're only escaping the `\r` character in the CRLF pair and then the line ends.

Comment: @Biffen so I should change CR LF -> LF?

Comment: @Wicia Yes. E.g. with `dos2unix`.